# undirected c++ graph with a direction

Tags: c++, graph, project-structure

I want to create a Graph in C++ that has directions, with directions I don't mean the direction of an edge but what I want is an undirected graph where the edges have a direction to the next vertex, for example lets consider we are in vertex1

```
up      = vertex2
right   = vertex3
down    = vertex4
left    = vertex5
```

Lets consider the following basic classes

```
 Class Edge{
    //To save an connection between two vertexes 
    Vertex point1;
    Vertex point2;
 }

 Class Vertex
 {
     string description;
 }
```

For this problem I came up with some possible solutions.

**1.** Give the vertexes a map with a direction (enum) and another Vertex for that direction (nullptr if no edge in that direction).

*disadvantage* is that we have to save directions on both vertexes or loop all other vertexes to see if it's connected to the current vertex.

*pro*? we don't need edges.

**2.**
Add an variable to the Edge object that contains a direction, we can make a rule that the direction is from point 1 to 2, so if the value of direction is down than the direction from point2 to point1 is up. We can save a list with all edges.

Also an important difference is that solution 1 save the edges in the vertexes and solution 2 in a class that contains a list with edges.

**Context**

What is important, is that I want to be able to set my position on a vertex and move around, when moved around I need to remember that I have used the connection between the vertexes. With solution 1 I can add a map for visited that has an enum direction (same as the concept to save the directions).
With solution 2 I could add a bool visited. I need to save the 'visited' variable because I want to test an edited [dijksta algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) based on visited edges.

**In short, how should I create a undirected graph where the edges have a direction (direction as in up, down, left,right from current vertex).**

What would you guys advise me to do?

Comment: We'd have to know what you're planning to do with this hypothetical data structure before we can help you design it. The answer to your two questions will likely fall right out of the operations you want to perform on it. In fact, as currently described, it sounds like you might be trying to represent a grid, in which case you'd be better off with a simple two-dimensional array and no "edges" at all.

Comment: @Ixrec I've added some context, hope it helps. When generating the vertexes I save them in a two dimensional array so I can easily print them.

Comment: Honestly, your whole question description looks very confused to me, I have no clue what your problem is. Why don't you google for "graph in c++" and use one of the data structures you will find by that search?

Comment: @DocBrown In short,  how should I create a undirected graph where the edges have a direction (direction as in up, down, left,right from current vertex).

Comment: Since you mention 2D arrays, did you consider representing your graph as a matrix? can you tell us more about your needs?

Comment: How many vertexes do you expect to deal with? <100? <1000? >100,000?

Comment: @DocBrown Around 400

Comment: @coredump The reason I decided to chose a graph is because I want to save the edges i've used, (and later disable some edges).

Comment: For 400 vertices, an adjacency matrix should be sufficient. Either create your own (with your "direction enum" as matrix entries), or use   http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html

Comment: The way I understand your post, you have a self-contradictory idea: You cannot create an *undirected* graph that is, at the same time, *directed*...

Comment: @ray directed means that the edge has a direction for example from vertex1 to vertox2 but not from vertex2 to vertex1. what i mean with direction is that vertex2 has an connection with vertex1 and the direction is above, right, bottom or left from this vertex. I guess position would be a better word.

Comment: In that case, you should clarify and use correct terminology. The [kinds of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) that go by those names have very specific properties. Still, if you want to know left/right/up/down, you probably want to use a *tree*. For example, a binary tree has a root with left + right nodes. You should create a more generic tree that allows up/down nodes as well. If this helps, let me know and I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @ray could i still use the dijkstra algorithm ? I try to explain it in the first paragraph with examples

Comment: Since Dijktra's algorithm is to find the shortest path in a graph, which seems different from your intended goal, then I'm not sure it's necessarily appropriate. If you use a tree, you can still traverse the entire thing and mark the visited nodes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your graph up into areas of fixed size.
Each areas vertices are now your fixed points of reference
Give your edges direction as they change position
Calculate your destination as vertices formed by edges from your fixed areas vertices.
Log the vertices, duration and or speed at each direction change
You can now pre-plot an arc or angle if required for a view or surface

Adding your direction as a would be compass direction from vertex 1 (origin) to vertex 2 (destination) would be as simple as determining if the vertices of the origin are greater or lower than the vertices of the destination. As for where you would store this value, this would be programmers discretion.
A similar method is employed by the game Minecraft. Searching on this might be of some aid.